# Drupal8 installation with Lando

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, drupal-8, lando

I am having this error when I try to install drupal8 using Lando.

> Warning:
>   require(/app/vendor/composer/../ircmaxell/password-compat/lib/password.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66 Fatal error:
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   '/app/vendor/composer/../ircmaxell/password-compat/lib/password.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

I have already tried `lando composer install` and `composer update` but the error has persisted.

Answer (score 0):

lando restart then do lando composer install
this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems vendor directly is not available in your repository. Run lando composer install inside web folder then lando drush cr.

Comment: vendor dir shouldn't be in the repo if the dependancies are managed by composer.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps:

1. `Lando start`
2. `Lando composer install`
3. `install Lando drush cim -y`
4. `Lando drush cr`